# How to check function return value in an if statement without calling it

Tags: c, function, cs50

I'm trying to check the return value of the function in an if statement so that I will return its value if its 1, but it gets called when I do it in an if statement. Is there a way where I prevent the call in the if statement. I want to check all three function but if I checked one without if statement then it returns 0 and stops.

```
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        string chars = argv[1];

        if (check_length(chars) == 1)
        {
            return check_length(chars);
        }
        else if (check_rc(chars) == 1)
        {
            return check_rc(chars);
        }
        else if (check_alpha(chars) == 1)
        {
            return check_alpha(chars);
        }
    }


    string ptext;

    ptext = get_string("Input Text: \n");

}

int check_rc(string chars)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(chars); i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (!(i == j))
            {
                if (chars[i] == chars[j])
                {
                    printf("Key must not contain repeated characters. \n");
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int check_alpha(string chars)
{
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(chars); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(chars[i]))
        {
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters. \n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int check_length(string chars)
{
    int charLength = strlen(chars);

    if( charLength !=26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Equivalent: `if (check_length(chars) == 1) { return 1; }` No matter what happens, you are returning `1`. You are doing `if (a == 1) { return a; } else if (b == 1) { return b; } else if (c == 1) { return c; }` which does nothing more than `return 1;` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the return value in a local variable and use it all the way:

```
int check_rc_val = check_length(chars);
if (check_rc_val == X)
{
    return check_rc_val;
}

int check_rc_val = check_rc(chars);
if (check_rc_val == Y)
{
    return check_rc_val;
}

int check_alpha_val = check_alpha(chars);
if (check_alpha_val == Z)
{
    return check_alpha_val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is hard to understand but i am assuming that if you want to reduce theamount of unnessecary check you could apply the concept of short-circuit evalution of &&

or u could just not use (else if). and use 3 if statement instead.

all following(else if) is skip if one of the if statement before it is true.

hope this help.